# How to track foreground app usage time of particular apps on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

My customer needs a way to track app foreground usage on their Windows computer. Is there some open source cli tool or Windows API or some library I can use to get this data? Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

I tried Win32_Process API (doesn't have this info) and some tools like ActivityWatch/Kimai (didn't find the cli version).

Comment: You need an [Enterprise Software Metering](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27enterprise+software+metering%27&t=h_&ia=web) solution. Why try and script this, as this is a really deep active monitoring thing? There are several to choose from on the market. Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager is specifically designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit more than what you are looking for, as it is an app that can be used to view graphs for days/months etc, but check out Tockler https://github.com/MayGo/tockler